# EXEC works with value of variable, but not variable itself

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, dynamic-sql, execute

I'm attempting to run a series of dynamically created sql statements that are stored in a table through exec statements. While troubleshooting, I've simplified the process down to just attempting a single statement, and I've encountered a problem I'm not quite sure how to make sense of.

Essentially, I have a declared nvarchar(max) variable, @str_query. It's initialized with a valid sql select statement from my table of statements. Trying exec(@str_query) returns an 'Incorrect Syntax" error (message 102), and proceeds to list the statement in string form. When I print(@str_query) and copy the same line into exec(), however, it works as expected. I then made a separate nvarchar(max) variable @test_var and set it explicitly to that same string. Running exec(@test_var) works as expected, running the sql statement stored in the string. Setting @test_var to @str_query and then running exec(@test_var) also produces the error.

Basically, exec() is working with the explicit value of the variable, but not with the variable itself, despite the value of the variable being a static string coming out of a table. Any help would be appreciated to get it to work with the variable. Thanks!

Code below:

```
DECLARE @Queries TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ColumnName VARCHAR(100), TableName VARCHAR(100),SQLScript VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @Results TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(100), ColumnName VARCHAR(100), Result VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @STR_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT
declare @searchValue varchar(max)
set @searchValue = 'search'
DECLARE @searchColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
set @searchColumn = 'addr_line_1'

INSERT INTO @Queries(ColumnName,TableName,SQLScript)
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME AS 'ColumnName'
,   TABLE_NAME AS 'TableName'
,   'select '''''+TABLE_NAME+''''' as ''''TABLENAME'''','''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''' as ''''COLUMNNAME'''','+COLUMN_NAME+' as ''''RESULT'''' from '+TABLE_NAME+' where '+COLUMN_NAME+' like ''''%'+@searchValue+'%''''' as 'Statement'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%'+@searchColumn+'%'

SELECT @EndLoop = MAX(ID), @StartLoop = MIN(ID)
FROM @Queries

set @STR_QUERY = (SELECT top(1) SQLScript FROM @Queries WHERE ID = @StartLoop)
set @STR_QUERY = ''''+@STR_QUERY+''''
print(@STR_QUERY) -- prints 'select ''Table1'' as ''TABLENAME'',''ADDR_LINE_1'' as ''COLUMNNAME'',ADDR_LINE_1 as ''RESULT'' from Table1 where ADDR_LINE_1 like ''%search%'''
exec('select ''Table1'' as ''TABLENAME'',''ADDR_LINE_1'' as ''COLUMNNAME'',ADDR_LINE_1 as ''RESULT'' from Table1 where ADDR_LINE_1 like ''%search%''') --works
exec(@STR_QUERY) -- error
declare @test_var nvarchar(max)
set @test_var = 'select ''Table1'' as ''TABLENAME'',''ADDR_LINE_1'' as ''COLUMNNAME'',ADDR_LINE_1 as ''RESULT'' from Table1 where ADDR_LINE_1 like ''%search%'''
exec(@test_var) -- works
set @test_var = @STR_QUERY
exec(@test_var) --error
```

Comment: `set @STR_QUERY = ''''+@STR_QUERY+''''` adds quotation marks around the entire query making it a literal string with nothing to evaluate. (`select 42;` does something. `'select 42;'` is just a pretty string.) Aside: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @HABO, thanks for the best practice advice, but I'm not sure I understand the mechanics of why I don't want a literal string when using exec(). `exec('select ''Table1'' as ''TABLENAME'',''ADDR_LINE_1'' as ''COLUMNNAME'',ADDR_LINE_1 as ''RESULT'' from Table1 where ADDR_LINE_1 like ''%search%''')` is using a literal string, and it's executing the select statement as I'm expecting.

Comment: `select 42;` returns an integer. `select '42';` returns a string, though it may look like a number. `'select 42;'` _is_ a string, though it may look like a statement. `exec( 'select 42;' );` and `exec( '''select 42;''' );` are very different things.

Comment: @Habo playing around with my code, I think I understand now, and I got it to work. I had too many escape quotes throughout my statement, and was misreading what I was actually working with when I was trying to output it with that print(). Thank you!

Comment: It may be less confusing if you create a variable with a single quotation mark and use that to build your statement: `declare @Quote as NChar(1) = NChar(39); select N'ObjectName', @Quote + N'ObjectName' + @Quote;`. You also don't need many of the quotes that you are adding, e.g. your column aliases: `N'select ' + @Quote + Table_Name + @Quote + N' as TableName, ' + ...`.